# What is the default number of items that are retrieved in the Get Items action and what options are there for getting more than 5,000 items?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, flow

The placeholder text in the `Top Count` field in the [Get Items action](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#get-items) says:

```
Total number of entries to retrieve (default-all)
```

[image]

That placeholder text communicates to me that, by default, it gets *ALL* items in the list.

This official article from Microsoft, however, states that it only retrieves `100 items` by default with a maximum of `5,000` *if* that number is entered in the `Top Count` field:

[In-depth analysis into Get items and Get files SharePoint actions for flows in Power Automate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/working-with-get-items-and-get-files)

Can anyone please confirm:

- What is the default number of items that are retrieved by the `Get Items` action?
- What is the maximum number of items that can be retrieved by the `Get Items` action?
- What is the difference between the `Top Count` field and the `Pagination Threshold` setting?
- Do all these item limitations relate to how many items can be *searched* OR how many items can be *returned*?
- What options are there for getting more than 5,000 items from lists which [can technically store up to 30 million items](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)?

[This article](https://tachytelic.net/2020/04/use-rest-api-power-automate-get-over-5000-items-from-sharepoint/) suggests that the [Send an HTTP request to SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#send-an-http-request-to-sharepoint) action can retrieve all items in a list, thus overcoming a maximum limit of 5,000 - is that true?

**Edit:**

After comments, if I set `Pagination` > `Threshold` in `Get Items` settings to `100000`, when I save the flow, I get this error:

> Flow save failed with code 'InvalidPaginationPolicy' and message 'The
> pagination policy of workflow run action 'Get_items_-_*******_list' of
> type 'OpenApiConnection' at line '1' and column '1047' is not valid.
> The value specified for property 'minimumItemsCount' exceeds the
> maximum allowed. Actual: '100000'. Maximum: '5000'.'.

[image]

There is possibly other reports of this error [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-save-failed-with-code-InvalidPaginationPolicy-and-message/td-p/1485581) and [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Pagination-Error/td-p/835358).

**Related Reading:**

[How to get more than 5000 items from SharePoint Online in Flow](https://alextofan.com/2019/08/22/how-to-get-more-than-5000-item-from-sharepoint-online-in-flow)

[More action settings and four new connectors](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/four-connector-action-settings/)

[Working with the SharePoint Send HTTP Request flow action in Power Automate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/working-with-send-sp-http-request)

> While using `Get items` on lists with more than 5000 items with a filter
> query, you may observe that no records are returned if there are no
> items matching the filter query in the first 5000 items. To fix this,
> enable Pagination on Get items from the action settings menu when
> working with lists with more than 5000 items.

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/working-with-get-items-and-get-files#known-limitation)

Answer (score 3):

By default the `Get items` action retrieves only 100 items from a SharePoint list.

If you want to retrieve more items from a SharePoint list, you can enable `Pagination` via the settings of the `Get items` action.

You can retrieve a maximum of 100,000 list items:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

Here's the hint by Power automate flow related to 100000 limit

> The threshold should be a number greater than 0 and less than or equal to 100000.

[image]

Comment: Thank you again.  1)  What is the relationship between the `Top Count` field and this `Pagination threshold`?  Just so I understand correctly, say that I have a list of 500,000 items - and I wanted to use `Get Items` to iterate over all items in the list, what would I set `Top Count` and `Pagination` to?   2)  Is there official docs somewhere that say 100,000 is the max number allowed in `Threshold` field?  3)  Any clarification on whether this 100 and 5,000 item limit refers to how much *is returned* OR how much *can be searched* would be appreciated!

Comment: If you mention Top Count = 5000 and Pagination = 100000, Get Items action will fetch list items in batches of 5000 items and it will retrieve total of 100000 list items.

Comment: So it can *return* a maximum of 100,000 items, can it still *search* a list of 500,000 items?

Comment: check updated answer for limitation about 100000 items.

Comment: I have posted a new question which specifies a related query:  [Does the Pagination Threshold setting in the Get Items action relate to how many items can be returned or how many items can be searched?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303715/does-the-pagination-threshold-setting-in-the-get-items-action-relate-to-how-many)

Comment: Hi @user1063287, does my response answer your original question? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.