# Power Automate pagination limit is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, list-view-threshold, threshold

I have enabled the pagination for my Get Items and set the threshold limit 100000 (the maximum limit), however this does not allow, it is only saying we can have only maximum of 5000 for the threshold limit but the threshold configuration message says the number should be between 0 to 100000. While saving the flow, it is throwing the below error:

```
The value specified for property 'minimumItemsCount' exceeds the maximum allowed. Actual: '100000'. Maximum: '5000'."
```

The above threshold limit 100000 absolutely works with the manually trigger flow but doesn't allow in Automated flow.

I have seen this that many people have discussed this issue but no clear answers.

Example where this been discussed:

- [What is the default number of items that are retrieved in the Get Items action and what options are there for getting more than 5,000 items?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303692/what-is-the-default-number-of-items-that-are-retrieved-in-the-get-items-action-a)
- https://github.com/microsoft/powerapps-tools/issues/725

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you will need a Flow Premium Plan (Plan 1 or Plan 2) in order to set the Pagination threshold to more than 5000 items.
[image]
Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#looping-and-debatching-limits

I tested with Microsoft Power Automate Free license and it is the same as you said. The above threshold limit of 100000 definitely applies to manually triggered processes, but is not allowed for automated processes.
[image]If you create an instant flow or powerapps flow,  all actions in this flow use user's connections. If this user who triggers this flow has a premium license ,the pagination maximum is 100K.
If you don't have a Premium plan or if you want to get more than 100,000 items, you can use a Do Until control to loop through all items in the SPO list.
Please refer to:https://alextofan.com/2019/08/22/how-to-get-more-than-5000-item-from-sharepoint-online-in-flow/

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Did my response answer your question? If I misunderstand something, please let me know! If there is any other assistance i can provide, please feel free to let me know, i will do our best to help you.